# How can I get listChannels method return channels in an order I want?

Tags: chat, pubnub

We are implementing a chat application using Pubnub and in a short span of time, the number of channels for each user has reached into hundreds. In order to improve performance, I need the listChannels method to return channels in the most recently used first order rather alphabetical order which is of not much use to me.

I am hitting one roadblock after another and I very seriously considering ditching Pubnub altogether as it is creating more problems than solving them for me. Please help me with this.

Comment: Pretty unfair assessment but I am biased, of course, but this not the experience of thousands of customers and developers. We see that you reached out to support and we replied with some suggestions on how to implement your requirement. Channel Groups were not implemented with what you had in mind but still possible to customize depending on how many channels you are considering here.

Comment: I would like to have a chance to address the other *road blocks* you speak of. Perhaps some time with a PubNub solution architect would be fruitful? If not then please send other challenges you are facing to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and we will provide assistance... it's what we love to do, and it is a free service.

Comment: I am glad to hear that thousands of customers & developers are happy. Good for them. Please help me with this particular issue and that will be more than helpful. Also, I did contact the support, they forwarded the case to the higher-ups, but I certainly did not receive any suggestions.

Comment: You were not handed to higher ups. I responded to you and haven't heard back from you. Still willing to assist on this and the other *roadblocks* that we are yet to hear about.

Comment: I cannot access the ticket that was created. I was told that I can receive/respond on the email thread, but I don't see any update there.

Comment: @CraigConover can you help me?

Comment: Check your email for account activation email and a personal contact from me.

Answer (score 1):

Channel Groups were not implemented with what you had in mind. But you can keep a local list *most active channels*. Everytime the user publishes to a channel or receives a message or whatever your requirements are, just update this list.